# How to append and remove images in a div (javascript and html)

Tags: javascript, html, image, appendchild, removechild

I'm trying to make a function (in javascript) that removes an image I attached to a div in html, I am having trouble getting the image I want to remove. The overall idea is to be able dynamically attach and remove images w/o having to use multiple divs. 
Here is the function to append the image

```
function appendImage(imageSource, Id){
    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.src = imageSource;
    document.getElementById(Id).appendChild(img);
}
```

The reason I create img in the function (instead of outside) is so that I can attach multiple new ones to the div, if I don't it just replaces the image
Here is what I'm trying to for the removing the image

```
function removeImage(imageSource,Id){
    document.getElementById(Id).removeChild(img);
}
```

I cannot access img in the removeImage because it isn't in the scope. So is there a way to pass img into removeImage w/o making it global or maybe another completely different way not using append or remove?

I don't know if you need it but all i have in my html file is

```
<div id="image"></div>
```

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: How `removeImage` is called ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit - added Codepen example:

[click for Codepen example](http://codepen.io/dabalose7en/pen/ezZaQp)

To use removeChild(), it must be called *from the parent of the node* you are trying to remove. Your function would look something like this:

```
function removeImage(id) {
    var elementToBeRemoved = document.getElementById(id);
    elementToBeRemoved.parentNode.removeChild(elementToBeRemoved);
}
```

At its simplest, you could just require one parameter - the id of the desired element - and from that you can determine its parent node and remove it.

Edit for alternative:

Another thing you could try is have appendImage return something to reference later - either an id that you pass in, or a random number. This can be appended to the new img element, and you can reference that to remove it in the future.

```
function appendImage(imageSource, containerId, imageId) {
    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.src = imageSource;
    img.setAttribute('id', imageId);
    document.getElementById(containerId).appendChild(img);
    return imageId;
}

function removeImage(imageId) {
    var elementToBeRemoved = document.getElementById(imageId);
    elementToBeRemoved.parentNode.removeChild(elementToBeRemoved);
}
```

`var myImage = appendImage('my.jpg', 'image', 'testId123');`

and later on...

`removeImage(myImage);` or `removeImage('testId123');`

Comment: when I run the first code I keep getting that null is not an object for the elementToBeRemoved.parentNode... part? Also I keep running append and remove in a setInterval(), i don't think that matters thought

Comment: Check out this codepen example: 

http://codepen.io/dabalose7en/pen/ezZaQp

It has examples of both removeImage cases

Comment: If the parentNode returns null is not an object, it sounds as if the image div is not present? In the codepen I also added `<div id="image"></div>` per your original post.

Comment: yup when I looked at your codepen and implemented the alternative method into my program it worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

do you define the variable `img` in your `removeImage` function? It doesn't look like you do. In `removeImage` make sure you find that img somehow and store it's location in a variable that you can then use to remove it

Answer (score 0):

You could try counting the images in the div and giving each image an identity. So that you would know which image to remove when it is neccesary.

```
function appendImage(imageSource, Id){
    var imagecount = document.getElementById('image').childNodes.length;
    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.setAttribute("id", imagecount + 1);
    img.src = imageSource;
    document.getElementById(Id).appendChild(img);
}
function removeImage(ImageId){
   var elem = document.getElementById(ImageId);
   elem.parentElement.removeChild(elem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to traverse the DOM to find the children of the div.

```
function removeImage(imageSource,Id){
    var div = document.getElementById(Id);
    for( var i=0; i<div.childNodes.length; i++){
      div.removeChild(div.childNodes[i]); //you may need an if to only remove the images
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To build on what Wongesse said

Modern:

```
function removeImage(imageSource,Id){
  var div = document.getElementById(Id);
  var image = div.querySelectorAll('[src="' + imageSource + '"]');

  div.removeChild(image[0]);
}
```

jQuery:

```
function removeImage(imageSource,Id){
  $('#' + Id + ' [src="' + imageSource + '"]').remove();
}
```

IE 8+:

```
function removeImage(imageSource,Id){
  var div = document.getElementById(Id);
  var images = div.getElementsByTagName('img');

  for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
    if(images[i].src != imageSource){
      // not the image we are looking for
      continue;
    }

    div.removeChild(images[i]);
    break;
  }
}
```